# Javascript require to Typescript import

Tags: typescript

What's the typescript equivalent to this construct:

```
const session        = require( 'express-session' );
const FirestoreStore = require( 'firestore-store' )(session);
```

I tried many variations, but always ends up with a `FirestoreStore` object not properly initialize (ex. `options.database missing`)

Thanks!

Comment: https://medium.com/@Zenkilies/express-session-with-typescript-85bf6dff3dc9

Comment: @Oleg : I took a look at the link and I understand the idea behind but the code sample is not put in context of the whole solution and I can't still figure out a better approach then this : import session = require('express-session');
const FirestoreStore = require( 'firestore-store' )(session);